# Find Hypercube graph in graph with same size vertex set

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=2^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathrm{deg}(v) \geq n$. Is there a way to check whether there exists a subset $E'\subset E$ such that $G'=(V,E')=C_n$, $C_n$ being the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) on $2^n$ vertices? I am completely lost on this one and looking for any input on how to approach this.

Comment: Can you tell us in what context this problem came up? This is basically a more specific version of the subgraph isomorphism problem, which is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Comment: The graph $G$ represents the state space of some Markov chain $X$. I could show that if there is a hypercube graph $C$ embedded in $G$ a nicely defined restriction of $X$ to $C$ becomes a random walk which is not "too far" from $X$ in distribution.